# Upgrade an Apache Solr index from 1.x to 5.x (or later versions)

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solrj, bigdata

I am migrating from solr 1.0 to 5.3.0. I have copied all data directories to newer core data directories but i am getting the follwoing exception on starting :

```
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="/Resume/resume/data/index/segments_1a9"))): -9 
(needs to be between 1071082519 and 1071082519). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 4.0 and later.
```

Can any one tell to the detail process to to covert solr 1.x index data to 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only move from version 1 to version 3 in one go.

You should use the IndexUpgrader tool for the version of Solr that you are using

e.g for 3.0

```
java -cp lucene-core.jar org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader [-delete-prior-commits] [-verbose] indexDir
```

You may need to upgrade via intermediate versions. Ie. upgrade to 3.0 then to 4.0 then 5.0. You could script this.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexUpgrader+Tool

You need to do this on a cold index. You'll find lucene-core.jar in your Solr install directory.

Comment: Thanks a ton DavidG. 

I have upgraded the index but now I am getting the follwoing issue after upgrading the index data in some fields.

"Login_srl_no": "ERROR:SCHEMA-INDEX-MISMATCH,stringValue=1732113"

where 
<field name="Login_srl_no" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

Solr 1.0:
 <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
Solr 5.x:
<fieldType name="integer" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />

Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: Did you upgrade your schema ?

Comment: Yes. i updated schema manually. Do you know any better way to upgrading schema if any?

Comment: I don't know of an automatic tool. Did it work after changing the field, it seems they changed some types between 1.0 and 5.0.